# iOS 8.4 UITabelview scrollToRowAtIndexPath is not working in Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

I have `UITableview` which has dynamic row height using AutoLayout. 
In iOS 8.4, if set `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` or `setContentOffset` its not scroll to last indexpath. in iOS 9.x it is working. Kindly help

```
        [tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:arr.count - 1 inSection:RootArr.count - 1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
```

Comment: Please share your code?

Answer (score -1):

```
dispatch_after(0, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
});
```

It is OK